# Compute and label distance between points on a line?

Tags: qgis, labeling, distance

I have a line and I want to find and label the distance between the nodes (like the cad aligned distance). The `v.distance` GRASS tool from Processing Toolbox outputs an empty vector file. Is there another way?

[image: Final image]

Comment: So, saved line vector as dxf > opened it in a CAD program> exploded it > opened dxf in qgis > saved as vector > new column in attr table > $length > label it. But still don't know why v.dist cannot give result if someone can help, please suggest an answer.

Comment: Are you using projected coordinate systems or WGS 84? Also why would you want to use v.distance instead of calculating the length as an attribute?

Comment: I am using Greek grid.I understand that v.distance will give a result like the picture i have with my question,so i can label the distances between the points.I need a line vector so i can render the text "above the line".

Comment: You want something like this? http://picpaste.com/pics/line-cDE0fn12.1430330169.png Only thing is the line needs to be drawn from node-node

Comment: yes but it is a little tiresome to right click and give id at each node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GRASS tool **v.split.vert** and set the max number of vertices to 2.
Then , you just need to label the created splitted layer.

[image: split]